# T-SQL Date Range Selection

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server database with this table:

[image: SQL DB]

and I am trying to get `RatePrice` between specific dates for a certain `TypeID`  e.g.

```sql
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2022-02-26';
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2022-03-02';
DECLARE @TypeID int = 10;
DECLARE @RatePrice money;
DECLARE @RateDate DATE;

WHILE (@StartDate <= @EndDate)
BEGIN
    SELECT
        @RatePrice = RatePrice,
        @RateDate = @StartDate
    FROM mgaRate
    WHERE mgaRate.TypeID = @TypeID
      AND ((RateStart BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) OR
           (RateEnd BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) OR
           (RateStart <= @StartDate AND RateEnd >= @EndDate)
          )

    PRINT @RateDate;
    PRINT @RatePrice;

    SET @StartDate = DATEADD(day, 1, @StartDate);
END;
```

But the result is not correct:

```
2022-02-26
400.00

2022-02-27
400.00

2022-02-28
400.00

2022-03-01
400.00

2022-03-02
400.00
```

In February the price should show 300.00.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: You need to join a calendar table, instead of this `WHILE` loop

Comment: As a start, try: `... WHERE @Startdate BETWEEN RateStart AND RateEnd`

Comment: What values do you expect to be returned if your `select` matches multiple rows? With `top (1)` and `order by` you could select a single row each time through the <gasp> loop </gasp>. Aside: Have a look at the [`overlap`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/overlap/info) tag description. It explains how to compare two ranges to determine if they overlap with a minimum of fuss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a calendar table to get all the dates in the range you need, and for each date you can get the rate using a subquery from the original table:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2022-02-26';
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2022-03-02';
DECLARE @TypeID int = 10;

with calendar as (
    select @StartDate as d
    union all 
    select dateadd(day, 1, d)
    from calendar
    where d < @EndDate
)
select
  d,
  (select RatePrice
  from mgaRate
  where d between RateStart and RateEnd
  and TypeID = @TypeID)
from calendar
```

You can replace the recursive CTE with an actual calendar table.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bb62fbc77e66e646fd376b8f6a0cdcfd)

Comment: Hi, many thanks, that is just working great! I have however some problems:


-It seems that I cannot assign a column name;


-When the User selects some Dates which are not inserted yet the Query returns NULL, for this Case I have a default Value e.g.


`DECLARE @TypeRate money = 100;`


When I try this


`(select CASE WHEN NOT RatePrice IS NULL THEN RatePrice ELSE @TypeRate END AS 'myRate'`


it Still only shows NULL instead of the 100;


-I actually need to select more then the RatePrice but an `IF EXISTS` is required, not sure where?

Comment: @MichaelGralkeAugusto check if [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1004052bf1ff10a5d22355f4941aae89) works for you.

Comment: great, just working fine, with the exception of the last item: When I wish to include also the RateID it says:

 Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 18

Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: @MichaelGralkeAugusto like [this?](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c9fe80f688ea3dd5b1213e657751d631)

Comment: I can see both RateID and TypeID, but somehow the NULL Value is not picking up `DECLARE @TypeRate money = 100;` and the dates stop at '2022-03-31', please try to use '2022-04-02', it used to show 100 for both the 1st and the second of april.

Otherwise its perfect :)

Comment: @MichaelGralkeAugusto [I got you](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2e0c71f4cf773f6811bed70f9d319506)

Comment: It seems to be working fine, I will let you know later. It seems that this Calendar Table is quite helpful e.g. when you need to find out if some rooms are reserved or not.

Can it be also be used to get a SUM of all Rates for the selected Dates?

Comment: @MichaelGralkeAugusto yes it's a very useful tool. It is recommended that you create an *actual* calendar table with all the dates that you need instead of using a recursive CTE. By the way don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it was helpful ^^

Comment: Many thanks for your help, it seems to be working well now :).  Could please just let me know how to get the SUM of all Rates for the selected Dates?

Comment: @Michael no problem. I'd say that depends on what exactly you want to sum, but it should be possible to do with a simple group by and sum()

Comment: Hi Zakaria, all sorted, many thanks for you great support :)